# ¿Cómo hago que un atributo no sea autoincremental? Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo la siguiente clase y EF me toma el atributo `Nro_Abonado` como autoincremental.

¿Cómo lo puedo corregir para que no lo sea?

```
[Table("Abonados")]
public class Abonado
{
    [Key]
    public int Nro_Abonado { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public bool Propio { get; set; }
}
```

Muchas gracias desde ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para eso, tenes dos opciones.

- Usar **DataAnotations**:

  Podes usar la anotación [`DatabaseGenerated`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute.-ctor?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedAttribute.%2523ctor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8)

```
[Table("Abonados")]
public class Abonado
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Nro_Abonado { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public bool Propio { get; set; }

}
```

- Usar **Fluent Api**

  La otra posibilidad es definirlo sobreescribiendo el método
  `OnModelCreating` de tu DbContext y usando el método [`HasDatabaseGeneratedOption`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.primitivepropertyconfiguration.hasdatabasegeneratedoption?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Abonado>().Property(t => t.Nro_Abonado)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
}
```

Luego, de más está decir, deberías realizar las migraciones correspondientes.

Comment: muchas gracias! muy útil! lo tengo andando como quiero ahora!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a generar tu tabla de la siguiente forma:

```
[Table("Abonados")]    
public class Abonado
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
   public int Nro_Abonado { get; set; }
   public string Nombre { get; set; }
   public string Direccion { get; set; }
   public bool Propio { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! muy útil!

Comment: @JuanCruzNavone Estupendo!. Recuerda valorar siempre, las respuestas que te hayan servido para solucionar tu pregunta.

Comment: sisis la valoré, pero como soy novato/estudiante (no recuerdo bien el nombre) no se ve impactada mi valoracion. Saludos!